# Pivot Table: Expand/collapse all rows using keyboard shortcut

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-excel-2016, pivot-table, tree-view

In an Excel 2016 pivot table:

Is there a keyboard shortcut we can use to expand or collapse all rows at a given level? For example, CTRL + click the plus sign to expand all rows?

I'm aware that it's possible to expand/collapse all -- using the mouse and the right click *menu*. But I'm wondering if there is a way to do it a bit quicker with a keyboard shortcut, as is often the case with expanded trees in other software.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of your keyboard and mouse to accomplish it.

- To expand, press <kbd>Shift</kbd> and scroll UP with the mouse wheel
- To collapse, press <kbd>Shift</kbd> and scroll DOWN with the mouse wheel

Source: [Excel Pivot Table Shortcut to Expand and Collapse](https://www.pivot-table.com/2020/05/06/excel-pivot-table-shortcut-to-expand-and-collapse/)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know their is no single press keyboard shortcut for this, though you can use chained keyboard shortcuts.

1. Select the relevant field.
2. Press in order (not together)

- <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> to expand all
- <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>A</kbd><kbd>H</kbd> to collapse all

To only expand/collapse a single requires a bit of a cheat. You need the menu button <kbd>≣</kbd> which functions like a right-click. If your keyboard doesn't have one, press <kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>F10</kbd>.

- <kbd>≣</kbd><kbd>E</kbd><kbd>X</kbd> to expand single field
- <kbd>≣</kbd><kbd>E</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> to collapse single field
- <kbd>≣</kbd><kbd>E</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> to expand all
- <kbd>≣</kbd><kbd>E</kbd><kbd>C</kbd> to collapse all

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

Expand: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Scroll up</kbd>

Collapse: <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Scroll down</kbd>